# Check exchange connectivity status

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I want to check if the exchange server configured with the Outlook account is available before proceeding with my script. Currently, I don't check and if there's a connectivity issue the script will hang forever on this line

```
Set m_objNS = m_objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

and appear unresponsive.

If there's no way to do that from within the Outlook API, is there a way I could retrieve the exchange server address and ping it or set a 20 second timeout on the .GetNameSpace function?

Update: If there's a problem with the network adapter (like if it's disabled), the code can access the namespace object. The exchange mode will always be 400 until there's a prompt to authorise the code and the user accepts it. However, if there's a real (non-test purpose issue) like the exchange server is down (destination host unreachable), Outlook idle in the state "trying to connect" and you can't access .Session object or the MAPI.

There must be a way to tell if the server is down.

Answer (score 3):

Excel can return the status with a series of values. You can do an If then else to respond to the status in different ways. Notably if it is "trying to connect" it reports that it's Disconnected (300) at least in Outlook 2010.

Here is the code to return the value (msgbox in there just for ease of testing). The reference values in comments of the code but also available here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868474(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868474%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
Sub CheckExchangeStatus()
'olCachedConnectedDrizzle    olCachedConnectedFull   olCachedConnectedHeaders    olCachedDisconnected    olCachedOffline olDisconnected  olNoExchange    olOffline   olOnline
'600                           700                      500                         400                     200             300             0               100         800

 Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
 Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

 Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Dim ExchangeStatus  As OlExchangeConnectionMode

 ExchangeStatus = olNameSpace.ExchangeConnectionMode
 MsgBox (ExchangeStatus)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what your scriptd  does so without knowing here is my suggestion.

use the session object to determine if the account is offline.

assuming m_objOutlook is an Outlook.Application object

```
m_objOutlook.Session.Offline
```

or use the ExchangeConnectionMode

```
objOutlook.Session.ExchangeConnectionMode
```

and check for one of the below

```
            olOffline
            olNoExchange
            olDisconnected
            olCachedOffline
            olCachedDisconnected
```

Comment: The session appear as "online" even if there is a connection issue, it only appear offline if you specify "work offline" in outlook.

Comment: As I said in my post update, the script will hang forever at objOutlook.Session if the connectivity status is at "trying to connect"